# Send an Email from Sendgrid and firebase?

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, sendgrid, email

I have a user database on the firebase, I have created a python script using sendgrind API to send transactional emails to a customer.

What I am trying to do, when a new user will register in my app, I want to send him a welcome mail from Sendgrid api fetching his email from the firebase.

Possible solutions:

1. Use Google Cloud Functions: As I do not really understand how it works
2. Use Zapier for firebase and sendgrid integration, as this zap is no longer available.

Is there any alternate solution?

I want this automated mail feature(for newly registered users) as a standalone function. A fully separate program which will fetch data from firebase of a new user and send them a welcome message from Sendgrid.

I am using Python for scripting

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write a webhook listener at your server which will listen to webhooks fired by firebase on Adding a new row. Then you need to read the data passed by Firebase and Trigger your mailing functionality to Sendgrid.

Please refer the below url to get to know how to configure Firebase Webhooks: [Get to know firebase weebhooks](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/minimal-webhook)

Comment: I am importing the data from firebase in every 30 mins and checking the with previous database. If a new entry added to a database I will send a message. I want the script to run in every 30 minutes, how can I do that?

Comment: You can configure cron jobs for the same. Check how to implement cron jobs for your operating system.